# maven-war-plugin copying overriden directory to final artifact

Tags: maven-3

We're using `maven-3.3.9` with maven-war-plugin to generate my final war. We were having problems with out static files when they were changed because browser was using the cached version.

So we decided not to use query string version attribute after referecing those static files. Our choice was to generate our static files directories overriden the way the maven-war-plugin states in [Adding and Filtering External Web Resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) docs, section **Overriding the default destination directory**.

Here's how we done it:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        <webResources>
            <webResource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/resources/${parsedVersion.majorVersion}${parsedVersion.minorVersion}${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion}${buildNumber}</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </webResource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

We're also using another plugins to get the project version parsed and number revision also, but they're not important to this question.

The problem is that the static files directories are created correctly as we expected but its contents are also created in the regular way like we're not using `webResources` instructions, so I get my resources contents dir twice. I get resources dir with the dir I want and all dirs inside of this second dir are also in resources dir as sibblings of it. How can I generate the resource dir as it is doing now and not duplicating its contents?

My final output is something like below:

```
|--- resources
    |--- js
    |--- css
    |--- fonts
    |--- js
    |--- myoverridendir
        |--- js
        |--- css
        |--- fonts
        |--- js
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the same folder is coming from two resource directories

1. Through `src/main/webapp` as it is `warSourceDirectory`
2. It is specified as a resource in `webResources`

As you want only one copy, the one coming from `webResources`, the one coming from `src/main/webapp` need to be excluded. It can be done using `<warSourceExcludes>` tag.

For example, let us say `js` is one such folder inside `src/main/webapp` folder. It can be excluded using `<warSourceExcludes>js/</warSourceExcludes>`